# Is there a easier way to display my objects in categories?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have two models like this:

```
class ClassA(models.Model):
    ida = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    classb = models.ForeignKey(ClassB)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765)

class ClassB(models.Model):
    idb = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=765)
```

I want to show a list of all my `ClassA` objects grouped under a `ClassB` heading. This is the view I have:

```
def show_class_a_objects(request):
    class_b_objects = ClassB.objects.all().order_by('name')
    class_a_objects = ClassA.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return render_to_response('show_objects.html', {
        'class_a_objects': class_a_objects, 'class_a_objects': class_a_objects, 
    })
```

My `show_objects.html` file looks like this:

```
{% extends "base_show.html" %}
{% block content %}
</p>
<table>
<th align="left">Name</th>
{% for b in class_b_objects %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{b.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for a in class_a_objects %}
        {% ifequal a.classb b %}
        <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ a.get_absolute_url }}">{{a.name}}</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
</br>
{% endblock %}
```

Is there a better way of doing this instead of using the two nested for loops?

Comment: What does your ClassA model have to do with this though? I don't see it in your template.

Comment: @jdi I had a typo, fixed it. It's in the second for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def show_class_a_objects(request):
    class_b_objects = ClassB.objects.all().order_by('name')
    class_a_objects = ClassA.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

You don't need to query the ClassA objects like this to achieve the grouping you want. When you create a ForeignKey on your ClassA -> ClassB, your ClassB will contain a relation that will give you back all ClassA objects which have ClassB as a ForeignKey:

**view**

```
def show_class_a_objects(request):
    class_b_objects = ClassB.objects.all().order_by('name')
    return render_to_response('show_objects.html', {
        'class_b_objects': class_b_objects, 
    })
```

**template**

```
{% for b in class_b_objects %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{b.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for a in b.classa_set.all %}
        <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ a.get_absolute_url }}">{{a.name}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You still need a nested for loop, but you no longer have to loop over the entire range of every single other class and do comparisons to find the right ones.

If you want a bit more control, you should move this into your view again and prebuild the dict:

**view**

```
def show_class_a_objects(request):
    class_b = ClassB.objects.all().order_by('name')
    class_b_objects = [(b, b.classa_set.all().order_by('name')) for b in class_b]
    return render_to_response('show_objects.html', {
        'class_b_objects': class_b_objects
    })
```

**template**

```
{% for b, a_list in class_b_objects %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{b.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% for a in a_list %}
        <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ a.get_absolute_url }}">{{a.name}}</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update: Reducing number of queries**

As per the comments, I wanted to address the issue of increasing the amount of database queries from your original 2, to the amount of `1 + num_of_classb_objects`. This is because while the original ClassB query is 1, each of the `b.classa_set.all()` relation calls is another query to fetch the related ClassA instances.

If you want to try and test an alternative, you can check out this blog post on [efficient reverse lookups](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/)

Example (adapted from link to your model names):

```
qs = ClassB.objects.all()
obj_dict = dict([(obj.id, obj) for obj in qs])
objects = ClassA.objects.filter(classb__in=qs)
relation_dict = {}
for obj in objects:
    relation_dict.setdefault(obj.classb_id, []).append(obj)
for id, related_items in relation_dict.items():
    obj_dict[id]._related_items = related_items
```

Also, if you are running django >= 1.4, this functionality is supposedly official in the form of [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

I have not tested this, but I wanted to present it as something for you to look into if `n+1` queries are not acceptable to you.

Comment: @DiZou since you're accessing `A` via the reverse relation, you will be executing a SQL query once for your initial `B` lookup, but also a query for every single `A` instance you display. Say there were 10 `B`s, and each of those `B`s had 10 `A`s, you're now executing 101 SQL queries instead of 2 SQL queries that you were doing before.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: I deleted my last response after I realized that I think you don't know what you might be talking about... If a single `B` item has 10 `A` relations, that is **NOT** 10 queries to retrieve them. It is **ONE**. The query will be like "select A where A.B.id=B.id". Its a single query to retrieve the relations. So lets redo that math: The 10 `B`'s are actually one query total. And if each one has 10 relations, that is still 1 query per result. So its more like 11 queries, and not 101. Lets make sure we at least get the facts right and not mislead.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton: And furthermore, its obviously unrealistic that someone would actually be dumping the entire contents of two tables in a normal production query. Most likely it would be a filtered, or on demand situation to where you have to break the data up anyways.

Comment: @jdi yeah I totally botched the query count - and I know better - so sorry for that one. However, 11 queries instead of 1 or two is still too many when you can avoid it without too much trouble.

Comment: @jdi Thanks for the update, I'll take a look at your recommendations!

Comment: @jdi I got it working using the efficient reverse lookups link you posted. I had to modify it a little, but it only uses two queries, and then the dictionary is built in the view. Thanks!

Comment: Oh good. Yea the blog link I posted suggestions testing the overhead of building the dict vs doing the queries. This might be a situation where you want to make sure this view gets cached a bit, so that its not constantly rebuilding this data more often than it needs to.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the large number of queries generated by accessing each set of `A` via the reverse relation, you could do something like this:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> alla = ClassA.objects.filter().order_by('classb').select_related('classb')
>>> groups = []
>>> for key,group in groupby(alla, lambda a: a.classb_id):
...     groups.append(list(group))
```

Now you have an iterable of iterables! We are focusing on the class that has the foreign key simply because you only need to execute one query (that is more complicated, but could save you in the long run). What's happening above, is that we are sorting the list of `A` by `B`, and then saving each list of `A` into it's own list/iterable. Since `A` is capable of accessing `B`, you don't need to worry about iterating through `B`.

```
>>> for g in groups:
...     print g[0].classb # this is your grouping/header
...     print g           # this is a list of your classa instances
```

You can get a little bit fancier if you like to reduce the iterations through the generator, but I find that by focusing on the Model with the `ForeignKey`, you get much better SQL performance at the cost of more complicated code in your view. The complication is (IMO) negligible, since a large number of SQL queries can be the death of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll take a look at what you and jdi have recommended.

Comment: I should mention that if there are instances of `B` without any `A`s, they will not be displayed with this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could a [`ManyToManyField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) in your `class B` model to include multiple `class A` objects in every `object B`. Such that you only have to call that field to get all `class A` objects that has the same value of `class B`.